# How to find the derivative of $f(z)$ if $z\in \mathbb C$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

How to find the derivative of $f(z)$ if $z\in \mathbb C$

Let $z=x+iy$, then $f(z)=u(x,y)=iv(x,y)$ is it simply $u_x+iv_x=u_y+iv_y$?

Comment: You differentiate the same way as usual. The derivative of $z^3$ is $3z^2$, $e^z$ gives $e^z$, and $\sin(z)$ has $\cos(z)$ as derivative. At least for holomorphic functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f'(z)=u_x(x,y)+iv_x(x,y)=v_y(x,y)-iu_y(x,y)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}{h}.$$

Comment: These are the Cauchy–Riemann equations.

Comment: Given the phrasing of OP's question, it's perhaps worth pointing out that $f'(z)$ is only defined for $z$ where the second equality holds, that is, where the C-R equations hold.